# Merge the [n-tier] and [n-tier-architecture] tags

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

I noticed that we have a [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) tag and a [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) tag.
Although the first tag is used more (388 questions tagged "n-tier" vs 149 tagged "n-tier-architecture"), the second one has a more extensive tag wiki. I suggest we merge these tags, and use the text for [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) as it's tag wiki.
I do not have enough points in either tag to suggest a tag synonym, so I'm suggesting it here.