# Merge / synonymize [n-tier] and [n-tier-architecture]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request, synonym-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge the [n-tier] and [n-tier-architecture] tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141211/merge-the-n-tier-and-n-tier-architecture-tags)

With [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) tag having 348 questions and [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) having 163 questions, these 2 tags should be merged.

Also, [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) should be made a synonym of [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture).

Edit: I found out that [the system doesn't allow you to propose a synonym if the source tag has more instances than the target](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58036/allow-tag-synonyms-where-the-source-has-more-instances-than-the-target).

So I am now reversing my suggestion from [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) -> [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) to [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) -> [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture), effectively meaning [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) should be made a synonym of [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) as [this restriction is in place to ensure that the most popular tags always take preference.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58855/166025)

Comment: As I pointed out in [my own merge proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141211/merge-the-n-tier-and-n-tier-architecture-tags), the [tag:n-tier-architecture] tag has a far more extensive tag wiki. I feel we should use that tag wiki for the "main" tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to my opinion [n-tier](/questions/tagged/n-tier) and [n-tier-architecture](/questions/tagged/n-tier-architecture) tags are synonyms of each other. So someone with enough [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) will suggest it.